# Unable to give the Preferred Search Center in My Site Settings in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service, mysite

I am trying to give the Search Center URL in User Profile->My Site Setting ->Preferred Search Center.

Once I've given the url and clicking ok, if I again go to that location I am unable to see the new Search Center URL value.

Can you any one help on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug in SP2013, that by my understandings won't let you change the search center for my sites from the UI. The solution would be to do it with powershell instead.

At the first row of the code, make sure that you change it to the name of your search service application.

```
 $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search Service Application"
 $ssa.SearchCenterUrl = "http://url/site/searchcentername/Pages/"
 $ssa.Update()
```

To clear things up a little bit:

1. Log into your server where central admin is running.
2. Open up and run PowerShell ISE as an administrator.
3. Type Add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell. Execute. ( This is to add the SharePoint API for powershell. )
4. Type Get-spserviceapplication | ft typename . This will return the name of all your service applications. Look for name of your search application.
5. Copy the name of your search application, for example "Search Service Application"
6. Copy the code into the script panel. ( ctrl + r ) if it's missing.
7. Execute the script.

After the change you would still see the wrong URL in the Preferred Search Center but if you try to search, you will see that the change was made.

[Unable to change "Preferred search center" in My Site Settings](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b88b0672-659b-471e-b489-cb6ef047fead/unable-to-change-preferred-search-center-in-my-site-settings?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: I already tried this option,but it was changing all the site collection search.i want to use only for Mysite

Comment: did not worked for me even with Feb 2016 CU

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem to change the URL after you have found that you have missed something like the /pages/ segment follow below solution

resetting only **Sharepoint Search Host Controller** service from services.msc resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Today I am setting up SP2019 and the bug still exist.

To solve it, first go to your search service application. Update the Global Search Center. Then restart SharePoint Timer Service. Then update the to have the Preferred Search Center in MySite setup with the same URL. This time change is saved.